# How to detect keypress in C++ on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, events, sdl, keyboard-events

I'm writing an assignment that needs to show some event-driven programming paradigms so I think key press detection should work fine. I've google for some hours and I've found some solutions for Linux and Windows. Unfortunately, I'm on Mac. So, I've only come up with cross-platform SDL. But I've only worked with Python tkinter for events before but I'm only allowed to use C++ for this assignment. And I'm not really familiar with Xcode as well as C++ so I've no idea how to install SDL into Xcode's C++. Plus, I only need to detect key press, so some smaller library should also work fine. I'm wondering if there is a library that will fulfill my purpose. The program can be as simple as -

```cpp
while(true){ cout << "The key you pressed was " << pressed_key; }
```

.

Comment: Have you tried kbhit() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet :

```
SDL_Event e;
while (true)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                cout << "The key you pressed was " << SDL_GetKeyName(e.key.keysym.sym) <<endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add this line above the `cout` statement.

```
cin>>pressed_key;
```

Comment: i mean pressed_key is supposed to be something like event listener -.-''

Comment: Try adding `keypad(stdscr, TRUE);` to the code. Let me know if that works @Zet.C.N